# Errors when attempting to free memory after String operations

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks

this is the first time I have written anything over 20 lines of code with C and the first time I've worked with managing memory.

My code works fine without using free in the snippet, but I can't seem to call free on any of the char pointers I've allocated using malloc when I include the call to free.

The code snippet is here: http://pastebin.com/rY47bWyM

I'm compiling using clang on Minix 3.2.1, when free(catenate) is called the program crashes and dumps its core. If I add in lines to free other char* like token I get the same sort of error.  What am I doing wrong? In other parts of my program where I do similar string manipulations using strtok, strcat, etc. I am getting the same problem with freeing memory so I think I am misunderstanding something critical.

Comment: Post your code here.

Comment: What do you mean, the whole program or just the function I have with this code snippet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, @Display

Comment: In the linked snippet, you `malloc` `catenate` and then set it to `NULL`. That's a memory leak. After that you assign `catenate` to the return value of `strtok`, i.e. to already existing memory. Freeing such memory is illegal. (Such memory might even be on the stack, not on the heap.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Okay, I've removed that statement, and I changed that line to `catenate = strdup(token);` -- is that right? I still have the problem when freeing though.

Answer (score 0):

You can only `free` memory that you have allocated. That means that the pointer has to be a value returned from one of the `*alloc` functions.

In your code:

```
    char *catenate = (char *)malloc((MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * MAX_ENVP) + 1);
    char *token = (char *)malloc(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
    char *copy = (char *)malloc(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE + 1);
    char *temp = (char *)malloc((MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * MAX_ENVP * 2) + 1);
```

Here, you allocate meory for `catenate`. Right after that, you do:

```
    catenate = NULL;
```

which loses the pointer to the allocated memory. That means that you cannot free it later; that's a memory leak.

Then you re-assign `catenate`:

```
    if(path != -1){
         copy = strdup(sh->envp[path]);
         token = strtok(copy, "=");
         token = strtok(NULL, "=");
         if(token != NULL && token[0] == '/') catenate = token;
    }
```

Now, `catenate` is einther still `NULL` or it points to an address inside `copy`. (It doesn't point to `copy` itself, because it's the second token, if any.)

Later, you free it:

```
        free(catenate); // This line is problematic
```

Bang! `catenate` isn't the address of an allocated memory block. If it were equal to `copy`, it would free `copy`, because `strdup` also allocated memory. But it isn't.

The thing is: Don't free pointers that you receive from `strtok`. Such pointers point into already allocated memory, in this case, `copy`. Instead of freeing `catenate`, free `copy` after you're done. (But bear in mind: By freeing `copy`, you render `catenate` illegal, as it now doesn't refer to legal memory anymore.)

By looking at your allocation bonanza I see that you allocate too much. Not all pointers need to be allocated. That is only one use of pointers: To indicate the head of an allocated chunk of memory. More often, pointers just point into existing memory, for example the tokens in an existing string. Don't free such memory and don't allocate memory to such pointers first - you'll leak it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed reply. That has really helped understand my misconceptions I had when writing that code. :D